# jQuery selectors to get array of nodes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
  <li class="normal">Home</li>
  <li class="normal">Internet</li>
  <li class="normal">Movies</li>
  <li class="normal">Music</li>
  <li class="normal">Documents</li>
  <li class="normal">Windows</li>
  <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is, get the array of `<li>` elements which have the "normal" class and loop through them and add event listeners.

What jQuery code will return the array? I tried different combinations like:

```
$('.main-navigation.normal')
$('.main-navigation li .normal')
```

How can I get that array of nodes? How can I loop through them and add events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$('.main-navigation .normal')` or `$('.main-navigation li.normal')`

Using `$('.main-navigation li .normal')` you will select nodes inside `li` with the class `.normal` and with the `$('.main-navigation.normal')` you will select the element with both `.main-navigation` **and** `.normal`

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [jQuery.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each)

**Update**

This is untested, but try [toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/):

```
jQuery("#main-navigation li.normal").toggleClass('newClass');
```

Comment: +1 Hi, I wanted to mark both your and meep's reply as answers. I can't mark two! Both of you answered separate parts of my question. Thanks! :)

Comment: $("#main-navigation li").attr("class","normal") will set every li elements class to normal, not filter it.

Comment: Can you explain that code? In jQuery, I usually get confused after the second DOT (.) !

Comment: thanks. li.normal is also an option, and then remove .attr(), keeping .each().

Comment: Oh! What I want to  do is, set the class to something else on mouseover and set it back to normal on mouseout

Comment: Me too. But I think it basically says, take all li elements with attribute 'normal', and lop throug them.

Comment: And I want to do it for  all the elements that are inside that <ul> and have 'normal' class iniatially. Basically I am trying to get a 'highlight-menuitem-on-hover' logic.

Comment: If you only want to change color or have underline, just do it in CSS and not by using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To add events, you don't need to loop through them. jQuery will add the event to all of the elements returned with the selection. For example:

```
$("ul.main_navigation li.normal").hover(function(){
    //what happens on mouseover
    $(this).attr('class', 'highlighted');
}, 
function(){
    //what happen on mouseout
    $(this).attr('class', 'normal');
}
);
```

Or you can use jQuery.each to loop through them, say if you need to add them to an array or something like this:

```
$("ul.main_navigation li.normal").each(function(){
    //this iterates through li.normal one by one
});
```

Comment: Hi. I didn't know that! Thanks... Now your reply is the third one I want to mark as an answer! :)

Comment: And inside the function(){}, I set the class like `this.attr('class','highlighted');` ??

Comment: I edited the first bit of code in the answer. Saw you were trying to do a hover affect...

Comment: I put a jquery selector around this, like $(this).attr('class', 'highlighted');